# Folder name comparing - script

Tags: directory

I want to create an until-loop that reads the name of a folder and compares it with the folders in `etc/skel`. If it doesn't find it, the user must re-enter the name.
I also tried using grep (instead of find), but with no results.

```
read folder_1;

until [ $folder_1 != find /etc/skel/ -name "$folder_1" -type d ]; do
   echo -n "Incorrect folder: "
   read folder_1;
done
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-d` test for existence of a directory:

```bsh
read folder
until [[ $(readlink -f "/etc/skel/$folder") == /etc/skel/* && -d "/etc/skel/$folder" ]]
do
   echo -n "Incorrect folder: "
   read folder
done
```

Comment: But why just "-d" did work ?

Comment: It's one of the standard tests available. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest.

Answer (score 1):

this might do the trick:

```bsh
read folder_1

until [ `find /etc/skel/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "${folder_1}" | wc -l` == '1' ]; do
    echo -n "Incorrect folder: "
    read folder_1
done
```

be careful: when using `-d "/etc/skel/$folder"` like suggested in muru's post, users could enter nasty things like `..` or `../../../root/` etc. so this could be a security hole then.

Comment: +1 for the warning. I've updated my post to hopefully fix it.